# Cypress run on Gitlab CI/CD always failed but work properly on local run using Chrome image & node

Tags: gitlab, cypress, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I have configured my cypress test in the GitLab CI/CD pipeline,
However, in my local environment, it runs perfectly with no errors, however, when the pipeline job runs, only 2 specs are successful and the rest are in errors.

Cypress version: `7.7.0`

Chrome version: `97`

Running mode: `headless`

Here are the parameters of my file

```
dev_e2e_test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome97-ff96
  stage: test-e2e
  when: always
  script:
    - echo "Starting cypress test"
    - cd client/cypress-automation/cypress
    - npm install cypress
    - npm run testEndToEnd
    paths:
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 day
```

I don't know if anyone has ever seen this error?
thank you for your help

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: something like timeout, sometime without logs just it fails 
Here is the one: 
     `AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/button/div`, but never found it.`
I use cypress-xpath to locate some elements.

Comment: @AlapanDas but these erros doesn't occured on locally run

Comment: Ok. On your local, tests run faster than in a CI environment because of the availability of resources, so as a ground-rule always add extra timeouts in places where you think the tests might break. So from your error, it seems that in one of your tests cypress is not able to find a locator. FIrst find the line of code that's causing the issue and then add extra timeouts and try again

Comment: @AlapanDas 
I have already increased the timout almost 4 times but nothing has changed, 
also, I have increased some cy.wait() almost 5 times but still without success, I think there is another problem behind it.

Comment: configure you CI to emit screenshots upon failure. You can use those to determine what it was the CI was 'seeing' when it failed the tests. It is almost certainly speed as noted.